# java class issue

Tags: java, c++

With the help of some very nice people from this forum I've been able to translate some c++ into java language, but I'm not sure how to call this classes. Bassically what they are supposed to do is to return a "gen4 style" curve. If someone have an idea how to  get this running please let me know!

```
/*
Derived from gen4 from the UCSD Carl package, described in F.R. Moore, 
"Elements of Computer Music."  It works like setline, but there's an
additional argument for each time,value pair (except the last).  This
arg determines the curvature of the segment, and is called "alpha" in
the comments to trans() below.                         -JGG, 12/2/01

http://www.music.columbia.edu/cmc/rtcmix/docs/docs.html    (maketable/gen4)



trans(a, alpha, b, n, output) makes a transition from <a> to <b> in
<n> steps, according to transition parameter <alpha>.  It stores the
resulting <n> values starting at location <output>.
alpha = 0 yields a straight line,
alpha < 0 yields an exponential transition, and 
alpha > 0 yields a logarithmic transition.
All of this in accord with the formula:
output[i] = a + (b - a) * (1 - exp(i * alpha / (n-1))) / (1 - exp(alpha))
for 0 <= i < n
*/





import java.lang.Math;
private static final int MAX_POINTS =1024;

public class gen{
    int size;              /* size of array to load up */
    int nargs;            /* number of arguments passed in p array */
    float []pvals;       /* address of array of p values */
    double []array;     /* address of array to be loaded up */
    int slot;          /* slot number, for fnscl test */
}

public static void  fnscl(gen g) {
}

static void trans(double a, double alpha, double b, int n, double[] output) {
    double delta = b - a;

    if (output.length <= 1) {
        output[0] = a;
        return;
    }
    double interval = 1.0 / (output.length - 1);
    if (alpha != 0) {
        double denom = 1 / (1 - Math.exp(alpha));
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
            output[i] = a + (1 - Math.exp(i * alpha * interval)) * delta * denom;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
            output[i] = a + i * delta * interval;
    }
}

public static double gen4(gen g) {

    int i;
    int points = 0;
    int seglen = 0;

    double factor;
    double time  [] = new double[MAX_POINTS];
    double value [] = new double[MAX_POINTS];
    double alpha [] = new double[MAX_POINTS];
    double ptr   []; 

    if (g.nargs < 5 || (g.nargs % 3) != 2) /* check number of args */
        System.out.println("gen4 usage: t1 v1 a1 ... tn vn");

    if ((g.nargs / 3) + 1 > MAX_POINTS)
        System.out.println("gen4 too many arguments");

    for (i = points = 0; i < g.nargs; points++) {
        time[points] = g.pvals[i++];

        if (points > 0 && time[points] < time[points - 1])
            System.out.println("gen4 non-increasing time values");

        value[points] = g.pvals[i++];
        if (i < g.nargs)
            alpha[points] = g.pvals[i++];
    }

    factor = (g.size - 1) / time[points - 1];

    for (i = 0; i < points; i++)
        time[i] *= factor;

    ptr = g.array;

    for (i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
        seglen = (int) (Math.floor(time[i + 1] + 0.5)
                - Math.floor(time[i] + 0.5) + 1);
        trans(value[i], alpha[i], value[i + 1], seglen, ptr);
        ptr[i] += seglen - 1;
    }

    fnscl(g);
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: If memory serves me right, you cannot have free functions in Java. Everything has to be a (perhaps static) member function of one single class, and the class name must be equal (gasp!) to the *file* name. I think you don't have an outer class in your code.

Comment: Please mention the main method and sequence of calls.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that this classes are members of another class!!

Comment: @KerrekSB You may have other, non-public classes in the file as well.

Comment: @menemenemu: That's called "posting pseudo-code", and it's discouraged precisely for the reason that it throws people off. Please always post minimal, complete, compilable real-code examples of your problem (compilable to the extent that the *only* obstruction should be the problem in question, nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly and you want to execute your program, you need some adjustments to your code.

You need to have a class. To execute it, you need a special main method.

```
/** 
 *Derived from...
 */
import java.lang.Math;

class Gen4Func {
    class Gen {
        // insert from question
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prepare parameters
        // ...

        // call your function
        trans( ... );

        // do more stuff
        // ...
    }

    public static void  fnscl(gen g) {
    }

    static void trans(double a, double alpha, double b, int n, double[] output) {
        // insert from above
    }
}
```

Save this to Gen4Func.java (must match class name). Then execute from via

```
> java Gen4Func
```

As I said: If I understand your question correctly.

HTH,
Mike

Comment: Thanks and  sorry, I forgot to mention that this classes are members.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a fully object oriented language in terms of paradigms. (Not as c++ which is also procedural), that's why as Kerrek SB said all methods has to be declared and defined inside a class.
What he was mistaken is that a file can contain only one public class and it has to be named exactly as the file. But it can also contain any number non-public classes with arbitrary names.

To run the program, you have to first compile the file with javac [filename].java then run it with java [classname] without! .class

One more thing. You can't declare a method like this:

```
public void foo();
```

The compiler will consider it to be an abstract method and raise an error message.

Comment: Can you have non-public classes outside the public class, or only as nested classes? My Java is a bit rusty...

Comment: Outside as well. I think this was always possible, it was the inner classes that came later, with 1.1 if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Bulky, copypaste to Gen.java and try setting Gen class fields with test values in main() method.

```
/*
 * Derived from gen4 from the UCSD Carl package, described in F.R. Moore,
 * "Elements of Computer Music." It works like setline, but there's an additional
 * argument for each time,value pair (except the last). This arg determines the
 * curvature of the segment, and is called "alpha" in the comments to trans()
 * below. -JGG, 12/2/01
 *
 * http://www.music.columbia.edu/cmc/rtcmix/docs/docs.html (maketable/gen4)
 *
 *
 *
 * trans(a, alpha, b, n, output) makes a transition from <a> to <b> in <n>
 * steps, according to transition parameter <alpha>. It stores the resulting <n>
 * values starting at location <output>. alpha = 0 yields a straight line, alpha
 * < 0 yields an exponential transition, and alpha > 0 yields a logarithmic
 * transition. All of this in accord with the formula: output[i] = a + (b - a) *
 * (1 - exp(i * alpha / (n-1))) / (1 - exp(alpha)) for 0 <= i < n
 */
public class Gen {

    private static final int MAX_POINTS = 1024;
    int size;              //size of array to load up
    int nargs;            //number of arguments passed in p array
    float[] pvals;       //address of array of p values
    double[] array;     //address of array to be loaded up
    int slot;          //slot number, for fnscl test

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gen g = new Gen();
        //initialize Gen fields here..
        Gen.gen4(g);
    }

    public static void fnscl(Gen g) {
    }

    public static void trans(double a, double alpha, double b, int n, double[] output) {
        double delta = b - a;

        if (output.length <= 1) {
            output[0] = a;
            return;
        }
        double interval = 1.0 / (output.length - 1);
        if (alpha != 0) {
            double denom = 1 / (1 - Math.exp(alpha));
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                output[i] = a + (1 - Math.exp(i * alpha * interval)) * delta * denom;
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
                output[i] = a + i * delta * interval;
            }
        }
    }

    public static double gen4(Gen g) {
        int i;
        int points = 0;
        int seglen = 0;

        double factor;
        double time[] = new double[MAX_POINTS];
        double value[] = new double[MAX_POINTS];
        double alpha[] = new double[MAX_POINTS];
        double ptr[];

        if (g.nargs < 5 || (g.nargs % 3) != 2) /*
         * check number of args
         */ {
            System.out.println("gen4 usage: t1 v1 a1 ... tn vn");
        }

        if ((g.nargs / 3) + 1 > MAX_POINTS) {
            System.out.println("gen4 too many arguments");
        }

        for (i = points = 0; i < g.nargs; points++) {
            time[points] = g.pvals[i++];

            if (points > 0 && time[points] < time[points - 1]) {
                System.out.println("gen4 non-increasing time values");
            }

            value[points] = g.pvals[i++];
            if (i < g.nargs) {
                alpha[points] = g.pvals[i++];
            }
        }

        factor = (g.size - 1) / time[points - 1];

        for (i = 0; i < points; i++) {
            time[i] *= factor;
        }

        ptr = g.array;

        for (i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
            seglen = (int) (Math.floor(time[i + 1] + 0.5)
                    - Math.floor(time[i] + 0.5) + 1);
            trans(value[i], alpha[i], value[i + 1], seglen, ptr);
            ptr[i] += seglen - 1;
        }

        fnscl(g);
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks D1e. to initialize Gen I just have to use g(value,value..)?

Comment: Its basics, spend 5min in Sun's tutorials.. To initialize an object - you need to use no-arg constructor: Gen g = new Gen();. To initialize its state - you need to set fields: g.size = 3; and so on.

Comment: thanks, I was trying that but I get:  gen4 usage: t1 v1 a1 ... tn vn
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
 at Gen.gen4(Gen.java:94)
 at Gen.main(Gen.java:34)

Comment: Cmon.. how cant it be out of bound if you didn't initialize arrays with normal values:    
float[] pvals;       //address of array of p values
double[] array;     //address of array to be loaded up

Answer (score 0):

In Java, stand alone methods are not allowed. You should make them member of some `class`. In your case, it seems that 2 of your methods are using `class gen` as argument `fnscl()` amd `gen4()`. You can make them as member methods. The other one can remain `static` within `class`.

```
public class gen{
  // data ...

  public void fnscl () { ... }  // member method
  public double gen4 () { ... }  // member method

  // static method
  public static void trans(double a, double alpha, double b, int n, double[] output) { ... }
}
```

`main()` also should be part of some `class`. I leave that choice up to you.